# How to link an image in a grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've created a grid with multiple images and as you can see in the CSS below, I've used the "background image" property as opposed to the "img" tag in HTML. I want to be able to click on these images so that it opens up a webpage, but from the research I've done, it appears I can only link an image using the anchor tag which would require me to use the img tag in HTML. I've already laid out the grid itself so now I need to know what CSS I would need to fit each image within its respective grid box (then I can go back and add the anchor/img tags to my HTML). Please note I am extremely new to coding and have zero experience or coursework, so I likely have many errors in the below code. Please go easy on me.

Also if anyone can provide the correct CSS to make the grid fit my screen that would be awesome. I currently have the height set at 717px because that is what fits my personal screen, but obviously other people have different sized screens.

```css
.layout{
  display: grid;
  width:100%;
  height: 717px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.color {
  transition-property: background-color;
}

.color:hover{
  background-color: white;
}

.box{
  width: 100%;
}

.a{
  color: white;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
  background-image: url(https://dlcdnwebimgs.asus.com/gain/E11F9021-A684-4848-98D6-6DB2841EDE5D);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
      <div class="box a color">a</div>
      <div class="box b color">b</div>
      <div class="box c color">c</div>
      <div class="box d color"></div>
      <div class="box e color">e</div>
      <div class="box f color">f</div>
      <div class="box g color">g</div>
      <div class="box h color">h</div>
      <div class="box i color">i</div>
      <div class="box k color">k</div>
      <div class="box l">Computer Parts</div>
      <div class="box m color">m</div>
      <div class="box o color">o</div>
      <div class="box p color">p</div>
      <div class="box q color">q</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The div tag is not the most appropriate for links. Use the  tag instead with the href attribute like this:

```
<a class="box" href="http://example.com">text</a>
```

It's not really common using the background property to set the image for a link, instead of an img element. There should be a good reason to do so